# 2 projects in git: for defects and for new functionalities

Tags: eclipse, egit

I am using Egit and I have one master branch. I have a new requirement to add another project so that I can do defect fixing in one branch and implement new functionality in another one.

I did try to create a new local branch for defects using Eclipse, but how do I retrieve my class files? How can i manage to have two different projects using git and also merge both of them whenever needed???

Please recommend something that will allow me to manage two different projects and still be able to merge them whenever I want to... Or is this the wrong way to approach this problem? If not how do I retrieve my class files?

Comment: I am able to retrieve all the class files. It depends upon which branch you are in. If you are in master branch then the workspace project will show all the master branch files or if you are in the defects branch then the workspace shows you defects branch files. Am i correct?

Comment: Major grammar edits and reformatting to make the question more digestible.  Questions with really long questions will tend not to be read, in my experience.  I believe this still reflects the question that you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be doing this with two projects.
The biggest benefit of Git is that you can do whatever work you need on new branches. So whenever you need to do some bug-fixing work, you should create a branch off master (where master should represent the code that's been published).

Then, when you've fixed the bug, and the code in your branch has been released, the code should be merged back into master, to reflect the new state of the live code.

Entirely new features should also use this way of working, i.e. new work for a new feature on a new branch. You can then branch off branches if someone wants to fix a bug in your new, unreleased feature. And before releasing, you should always pull from master (resolving any conflicts) to ensure that you are releasing changes that includes whatever has already been released.

Comment: So you mean in my case i should create two new branches ... one for defects and one for functionalities ?  Master is the parent branch which should be used to deploy to my production environment. So if any week i need to host my defects and my neww functionalities then i should merge them in master branch and then deploy to my production environment?

Comment: Not just 2 new branches. Create a new branch whenever you need to do something, whether it's fix a bug or build a feature. Once the bug is fixed or the feature released, merge that branch back into master, and then you can delete the branch if you want. Whatever the next work is that you need to do can be on its own branch.